# Не рендерится массив объектов React

Tags: reactjs

У меня некий список статей, который нужно отрендерить и потом отсортировать по количеству голосов и по дате публикации. Возникла проблема, что после сортировки по количеству голосов, не происходит новый рендер, то есть сам массив отсортировался, но React это не понимает этого, подскажите почему?

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'h8k-components';

import Articles from './components/Articles';

const title = "Sorting Articles";

function App({articles}) {
   const [articlesNew, setArticlesNew] = React.useState(articles);

   const sortByUpvotes = (() => {
      setArticlesNew(articles.sort((prev, next) => {
         return prev.upvotes - next.upvotes
      }))
      console.log(articlesNew)
   })

   return (
      <div className="App">
         <h8k-navbar header={title}/>
         <div className="layout-row align-items-center justify-content-center my-20 navigation">
            <label className="form-hint mb-0 text-uppercase font-weight-light"> Sort By </label>
            <button data-testid="most-upvoted-link" className="small" onClick={sortByUpvotes}>Most Upvoted</button>
            <button data-testid="most-recent-link" className="small" onClick>Most Recent</button>
         </div>
         <Articles articles={articlesNew}/>
      </div>
   );
}

export default App;
```

Компонент Arcticles:

```
import React from 'react';

function Articles({articles}) {

   return (
      <div className="card w-50 mx-auto">
         <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Title</th>
               <th>Upvotes</th>
               <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {
               articles.map(item => {
                  return <tr data-testid="article">
                     <td data-testid="article-title">{item.title}</td>
                     <td data-testid="article-upvotes">{item.upvotes}</td>
                     <td data-testid="article-date">{item.date}</td>
                  </tr>
               })
            }
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   );

}


export default Articles;
```

Comment: @entithat а можно подробнее?

Comment: `setArticlesNew(prev => [...prev.sort((a, b) => a.upvotes - b.upvotes))])`

Comment: @entithat можете написать ответ, чтобы я мог отметить его правильным, и подробнее объяснить почему именно так?

Comment: useState смотрит на изменение значения, при работе с массивами, useState не проверяет изменился ли массив или нет, ему нужен новый массив с данными.

Comment: @xantin, изза асинхронной работы setAcrticlesNew содержание articles иногда будет не то, которое вы ожидаете. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync